# xPath last select element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, selenium

Can someone help me to bring this code working? I have several select fields and I only want the last one in my variable.

```
variable = browser.elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="nested-field"]//select[last()]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**This is a FAQ**: The `[]` operator in XPath has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator. This is why brackets must be used to change the default operator priorities. There are at least several similar questions with good explanations -- search for them and read and understand.

**Instead of**:

```
//div[@class="nested-field"]//select[last()]
```

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class="nested-field"]//select)[last()]
```

Comment: I don't understand why //div[@class="nested-field"]//select would match anything.

Comment: @pguardiario: Not "match" but "select". `//div[@class="nested-field"]//select` selects any `select` element that is a descendent of any `div` element, whose `class` attribute has the value of `"nested-field"` .

Comment: I guess my question is why is it //select instead of /select?

Comment: @pguardiario: `someElement/select` selects only the children (named `select`) of `someElement`. On the other side, `someElement//select` selects any descendant (child, grandchild, grand-grand-child, ..., etc.) named `select`.

Answer (score 0):

is the class attribute an exact match?
if the mark up is like this

```
<div class="nested-field other">
...
```

then you'll have to either match by the exact class or use xpath contains.